# thrift: changing from tSimpleServer to TNonblockingServer

Tags: c++, connection, thrift

I have a simple thrift server:

```
  shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new MyProcessor(handlerTrace));
  shared_ptr<TServerTransport>  serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
  shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
  shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory>  protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

  TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport,
               transportFactory, protocolFactory);
```

and able to connect with the following lines:

```
   boost::shared_ptr<TSocket> socket(new TSocket("localhost", port));
   boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
   boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

   MyClient client(protocol);
```

Now I want to change the server to `TNonblockingServer`. Therefore I changed the server code to the following:

```
  shared_ptr<TServerTransport>  serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
  shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());
  TNonblockingServer server(processor,
                protocolFactory,
                port);
```

The client is unchanged. Now the server complaints about the client with the following error message:

```
Thrift: Mon Aug 19 22:55:43 2013 TNonblockingServer: Serving on port 9990, 1 io threads.
Thrift: Mon Aug 19 22:55:43 2013 TNonblockingServer: using libevent 2.0.16-stable method epoll
Thrift: Mon Aug 19 22:55:43 2013 TNonblocking: IO thread #0 registered for listen.
Thrift: Mon Aug 19 22:55:43 2013 TNonblocking: IO thread #0 registered for notify.
Thrift: Mon Aug 19 22:55:43 2013 TNonblockingServer: IO thread #0 entering loop...
Thrift: Mon Aug 19 22:55:48 2013 TNonblockingServer: frame size too large (2147549185 > 268435456) from client <Host: 127.0.0.1 Port: 57130>. Remote side not using TFramedTransport?
```

What do I do wrong? Comments? I am using the 1.0-dev version of thrift as only this version supports multiplexing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using TFramedTransport instead of TBufferedTransport in your client.
Look at this example: http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC%2B%2B

Another thing to notice is that according to the example above TNonblockingServer takes a ThreadManager as an argument.