# Apache Thrift tutorial client stuck when using 2 clients - how to make the server multitask?

Tags: java, thrift

I'm executing [Apache Thrift tutorial for Java](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/java).

When running 2 client processes at the same time, the server doesn't accept the 2nd client. Only after the first client finishes, the second one is accepted by the server.

**Can anyone explain what's going on?**

How can I make the server accept several connections in several threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can anyone explain what's going on?**

You already found it out: The `TSimpleServer` allows only for one connection at a time. It will be available again when the first client disconnects.

**How can I make the server accept several connections in several threads?**

Use one of the [threading servers](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/server), whichever [fits your use case best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543835/tnonblockingserver-tthreadedserver-and-tthreadpoolserver-which-one-fits-best-f).

- [TThreadPoolServer](http://people.apache.org/~thejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/server/TThreadPoolServer.html)
- TThreadedSelectorServer
- [TNonBlockingServer](http://people.apache.org/~thejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/server/TNonblockingServer.html)
- The [half-sync/half-async server](http://people.apache.org/~thejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/server/THsHaServer.html)

Please note, that [some of the servers require the client to use `TFramedTransport`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337873/thrift-changing-from-tsimpleserver-to-tnonblockingserver).

Answer (score 2):

Based on other answers, below is the code to enable executing multiple clients simultaneously.

Server (simple):

```
CalculatorHandler handler = new CalculatorHandler();
Calculator.Processor processor = new Calculator.Processor(handler);
TNonblockingServerSocket serverTransport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(9090);
THsHaServer.Args args = new THsHaServer.Args(serverTransport);
args.processor(processor);
args.transportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory());
TServer server = new THsHaServer(args);
server.serve();
```

Client:

```
transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9090);
transport.open();
TProtocol protocol = new  TBinaryProtocol(new TFramedTransport(transport));
Calculator.Client client = new Calculator.Client(protocol);
perform(client);
```